# Since doing a clean project, android app can't find XML values

Tags: java, android

I keep getting errors in my class now that I ran a "clean" in Eclipse on my android app.

My XML is in /res/layout/main.xml and has the following code, my audio files are in /res/raw/ and are named "intro.mp3" and "newintro.mp3"...

When I call the values in my code though, I now get "cannot be resolved or is not a field" this has only happened since I ran clean on my project.

```
    final MediaPlayer oldintro = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.intro);
    final MediaPlayer newintro = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.newintro);
```

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: You probably have an error in your XML resources that prevent generation of the R class -> references are not found. Can you post your main.xml? And do you have any other resources? *(or you imported `android.R.*` instead of `R.*` by accident)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directory raw must be a subdirectory of res... Probably this is the problem

Comment: Are there some import about the "R" class in your file? If yes, try to remove this import, and re-clean the project